# What's the purpose of the message that appears?

Tags: macos, file

I cannot understand this message about the other computer. M1 is the other computer. I do copy on M1, but usually,[image] that has nothing to do with the other computer. I do not understand.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks to be the Universal Clipboard in action. You've Copied a folder in the Finder on the M1, and so the clipboard on the other Mac is receiving the entire contents.

If you press Paste on the receiving Mac, you will add those files to the current window location. Alternatively, you can press the x button on the end of the progress bar, to quit the transfer.

If "Handoff" is enabled, copy and paste actions are linked on Macs with the same AppleID that are within close proximity.

https://support.apple.com/HT209460